# Run minecraft.jar in Java with ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, minecraft, processbuilder

I'm trying to run Minecraft.jar (the game) in Java. I tried to run it with this code:

```
String LibsAndStuff = String.format(
        "%s/minecraft.jar:%s/lwjgl.jar:%s/lwjgl_util.jar:%s/jinput.jar", 
        OSDetector.getMinecraftJarDiretoryFullPath(), 
        OSDetector.getMinecraftJarDiretoryFullPath(), 
        OSDetector.getMinecraftJarDiretoryFullPath(), 
        OSDetector.getMinecraftJarDiretoryFullPath());

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-Xmx2048M", "-Xms512M", "-cp", 
        LibsAndStuff, String.format("-Djava.library.path=%s/natives", 
        OSDetector.getMinecraftJarDiretoryFullPath()), 
        "net.minecraft.client.Minecraft");
pb.directory(new File(OSDetector.getMinecraftJarDiretoryFullPath()));

try {
    Process p = pb.start();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

`OSDetector.getMinecraftJarDiretoryFullPath()` returns the String with path to .minecraft(in example "/home/user/.minecraft").  Nothing shows up in the Eclipse console. I don't know what's wrong, as the exact same command launched in bash worked fine.

@EDIT
`C:\Users\Łukasz\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin/minecraft.jar:C:\Users\Łukasz\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin/lwjgl.jar:C:\Users\Łukasz\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin/lwjgl_util.jar:C:\Users\Łukasz\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin/jinput.jar`
This is that String. I changed / to \, but it didn't help :<

Comment: You should consider removing that swear word from the code.

Comment: On topic: Can you `println` the classpath string you build?

Comment: @SkyDan I bowdlerized it in an edit.

Comment: @xaxes everyday we learn something new :) also maybe instead of invoking `OSDetector.getMinecraftJarDiretoryFullPath()` everywhere in your code invoke it just once, store its result in some reference like `String dir = OSDetector.getMinecraftJarDiretoryFullPath();` and use that reference where you need that result like `String.format("%s/minecraft.jar:%s/lwjgl.jar:%s/lwjgl_util.jar:%s/jinput.jar", dir, dir, dir, dir)`.